# Similar to Kruskal-Wallis Test for multidimensional vector

Tags: statistics

I need to do the similar kind of test as Kruskal-Wallis Test but for the multidimensional vector. Would you please kindly suggest such kind of test or provide some references for N-d case.

Thank you for your help.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that the component distributions vary only in their location (as per Kruskal-Wallis) then under the null hypothesis that the two vectors are equal, you can perform the Kruskal-Wallis procedure on the *difference* in the component sample means, since under the null, each such difference should have the same distribution.

If you don't want to rely on just location differences, you can use the [Rust-Fligner modification of the Kruskal-Wallis](http://books.google.com/books?id=gYIKAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA211&lpg=PA211&dq=Rust-Fligner%20statistics&source=bl&ots=JZnOQ22rd4&sig=0FeRj8S3FzHhXMf7XIQHHnvIrN0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jt3PU5ieEcvNsQSIjILoBQ&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Rust-Fligner%20statistics&f=false), where you only need to assume that the difference in means statistics are all part of the same location-scale family.